# Generate changelog from commit and tag

Tags: git, bitbucket, changelog

I'm trying to generate changelog to a project (repo in bitbucket.org), but I can't find an easy solution. We are using [this pattern](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/dev/git-commit-msg.html)

```
(<type>(<scope>): <subject>)
```

to fill the commit messages, and tags to version (0.1, 0.2, 0.3).

Is there anything out-of-the-box (some script, npm package, etc...) or the best thing I can do is write some custom script using git log and parse the data (commit messages, etc...)?

I know there is an github-changelog-creator, but I can't use as long as this repo is in a bitbucket repo.

Comment: I firmly believe that changelogs should be created manually. Commit histories are very granular and exist at a technical level. Changelogs should be less granular and focused on user-facing changes.

Answer (score 30):

We are using this simple shell script to generate hierarchical change log sorted by tags with the latest tag on top.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
previous_tag=0
for current_tag in $(git tag --sort=-creatordate)
do

if [ "$previous_tag" != 0 ];then
    tag_date=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:'%ad' --date=short ${previous_tag})
    printf "## ${previous_tag} (${tag_date})\n\n"
    git log ${current_tag}...${previous_tag} --pretty=format:'*  %s [View](https://bitbucket.org/projects/test/repos/my-project/commits/%H)' --reverse | grep -v Merge
    printf "\n\n"
fi
previous_tag=${current_tag}
done
```

And you can put it in the project root as some shel file and run it (depending upon your platform you might need to make it executable) as below

```
sh change-log-builder.sh > changelog.md
```

And the resulting changelog.md looks like this

---

### v1.1.0 (2017-08-29)

- Adds IPv6 support [View]
- Adds TreeMaker class and its test. [View]

### v1.0.9 (2017-08-22)

- Updates composer.json.lock [View]

### v1.0.8 (2017-08-22)

- Adds S3Gateway as substitute class [View]
- Removes files no more used [View]

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using this (with some changes) for our alpha and beta channels.