# Generating Release Notes (CHANGELOG.md)

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am using Bitbucket on an enterprise team and I am trying to find a solution for generating release notes (CHANGELOG.md) from my Bitbucket repository. I have tried nearly all npm solutions but they all fail due to them making an assumption that my repository is a GitHub repository. Ideally I would like to have some type of integration with Jira since our stories are linked, e.g., populate the changelog with Jira story descriptions.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865597/generate-changelog-from-commit-and-tag/46033999